# How to call OpenCV in Sikuli/Jython?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I'm aware that Sikulix uses Jython and OpenCV for it's template matching, but I'm interested in performing some more complicated image processing tasks. Is it possible to directly access OpenCV in Sikulix/Jython, and are there any examples of how one would do this?

Comment: This question has already been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996689/how-to-use-python-opencv-functions-in-sikuli/13988019